# Add new row to existing CSV using Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I am trying to add a new row to an existing `csv` file. The new `row` is from a `for loop` which is `appended` to `string list` and is saved to a `DataFrame`. I don't want the entire `loop` to be saved in memory and then saved to the `csv` file. I prefer to add each row to the file separately updating it as the loop iterates because it is a long running loop and not having to wait until the entire loop is completed.

I am able to loop over the group but it causes duplicated rows.

```
names = []
addresses = []
pages = np.arange(10300, 10400, 1)

for page in pages:

    page = requests.get(
        "https://www.testpage.com/" + str(page), headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

    company = soup.find_all('main')

    for container in company:

        name = container.find("b", {"id": "company_name"})
        names.append(name.text.strip())

        address = container.find('div', attrs={'class': 'text location'})
        addresses.append(address.text.strip())

    companies=pd.DataFrame({
        'name': names,
        'address': addresses
    })

    companies.to_csv(r'b_10300_10400.csv', mode='a', header=False)
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reset the `names` and `addresses` variable each time through the loop:

```
pages = np.arange(10300, 10400, 1)

for page in pages:
    names = []
    addresses = []

    page = requests.get(
        "https://www.testpage.com/" + str(page), headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

    company = soup.find_all('main')

    for container in company:

        name = container.find("b", {"id": "company_name"})
        names.append(name.text.strip())

        address = container.find('div', attrs={'class': 'text location'})
        addresses.append(address.text.strip())

    companies=pd.DataFrame({
        'name': names,
        'address': addresses
    })

    companies.to_csv(r'b_10300_10400.csv', mode='a', header=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the standard `csv` module which is built to write things row at a time instead. You aren't doing any `pandas` related processing and its just getting in the way.

```
import csv

pages = np.arange(10300, 10400, 1)

with open('b_10300_10400.csv', mode='a', newline='') as outfile:

    writer = csv.writer(outfile)

    for page in pages:
    
        page = requests.get(
            "https://www.testpage.com/" + str(page), headers=headers)
    
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    
        company = soup.find_all('main')
    
        for container in company:
    
            name = container.find("b", {"id": "company_name"}).text.strip()
            address = container.find('div', attrs={'class': 'text location'}).text.strip()
            writer.writerow((name, address))
```